# Gulp task finished before the output files are generated

Tags: typescript, gulp, webpack

---- Updates on top ------

Some friends point out that I should return the stream from the task. That's right but doesn't help.

In fact, in my first version, I returned the stream, the `var rs` parts once were `return`.

The problem is, the compiled js files are generated *after* the task has completed. So no matter I use the `done` callback, or return the stream from task, the task has really completed, and the next task is started, but the generated files are not ready.

---- Here's the original question ----

I've a gulpfile.js to firstly compile a bunch of .ts file into js, and then pack the output js files throught webpack. Here're the important parts of my gulpfile.js:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const ts = require("gulp-typescript");
const webpack = require("webpack-stream");

gulp.task("default", ["build"]);
gulp.task("build", ["compile", "pack"]);
gulp.task("compile", task_compile);
gulp.task("pack", ["compile"], task_pack);

function task_compile(done) {
    return util_compile_ts("main", done);
}

function task_pack(done) {
    return util_pack_js("main", done);
}

function util_compile_ts(proj, done) {
    const dirSrc = "src/" + proj;
    const dirCompiled = "out/compiled/" + proj;
    const dirBuilt = "out/built";

    var tscfg = require("./" + dirSrc + "/tsconfig.json").compilerOptions;
    var rs = gulp
        .src(dirSrc + "/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(ts(tscfg))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirCompiled))
        .on("end", done);
}

function util_pack_js(proj, done) {
    const dirSrc = "src/" + proj;
    const dirCompiled = "out/compiled/" + proj;
    const dirBuilt = "out/built";

    var wpcfg = require("./" + dirSrc + "/webpack.config.js");
    wpcfg.context = path.resolve(dirSrc, wpcfg.context)
    wpcfg.output.path = path.resolve(dirSrc, wpcfg.output.path)
    var rs = gulp
        .src(dirCompiled + "/**/*.js")
        .pipe(webpack(wpcfg))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirBuilt))
        .on("end", done);
}
```

If I run `gulp compile` and then `gulp pack`, no problem. But when I run just `gulp`, and error is occurs:

```
Error: Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'
```

And the path of compiled js files are listed, the path itself is okay, but hadn't be copied to the `compiled` folder.

I observed the process of ts compilation, and I found,
**The ts task finished before the output files are actually generated.** When run `gulp compile`, the gulp task showed finished and 1 or 2 seconds after, the generated files appeared in the `compiled` folder.

So when I run `gulp`, the `pack` task will start immediately after `compile` task finished, at that time, the js outputs are not ready on disk, so the `pack` task failed because it can't find input.

So question is, how could I wait the compiled js files are ready and proceed to the next task?

---

P.S. I don't want use setTimeout for a hard coded waiting....

Thanks,
Anders

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this isn't the problem. In fact, in my first version, I've returned the stream, the `var rs` part once was `return`. But it didn't help, the file was generated **after** the task had completed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As per the [documentation for `gulp-typescript`](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#basic-usage) the returned stream of `ts` is not your JavaScript files. It's a combination of `.js` and `.d.ts`. Referring to [TypeScripts exampels](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#gulp) see how they select the JavaScript files in the stream.

Try changing your stream flow by selecting the JavaScript files and further more return the stream to let gulp handle the done callback for you.

```
function util_compile_ts(proj, done) {
  const dirSrc = "src/" + proj;
  const dirCompiled = "out/compiled/" + proj;
  const dirBuilt = "out/built";

  var tscfg = require("./" + dirSrc + "/tsconfig.json").compilerOptions;
  return gulp
    .src(dirSrc + "/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(ts(tscfg))
    .js
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dirCompiled));
}
```